# Add/remove copied files with Mercurial, TortoiseHg does it, but what's the command line variant?

Tags: command-line, mercurial

The Mercurial command `addremove` detects files that have been renamed according to a similarity ration.

TortoiseHg is also able to detect copies, ie. files that were copied on disk but not explicitly communicated to Mercurial as copies.

It doesn't appear that the `addremove` command have any options to detect copies, only renames. Does anyone know what the equivalent command line command and/or options would be to do this?

For instance, if I do this:

```
hg init .
echo 111>test1.txt
hg commit -m "initial" --addremove
copy test1.txt test2.txt
??? what do I write here to get the equivalent of: hg cp test1.txt test2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do it using the CLI. Only supporting moves means you can whittle down the set of files to be compared to those that are either missing or added.

I'm not sure how Tortoise does it, but I'd guess it's pretty expensive.

Comment: Yes, it is very expensive. It looks like they have their own similiarity implementation and just does the grunt work, ending up with the equivalent of `hg cp -A source target` type of commands. I'll put this on ice for now.